# Использовать ли в JavaScript .concat()?

Tags: javascript, методы, concat

Я учу все методы которые только увижу. Во время чтения документации MDN я увидел, что по производительности он плох. Но значка "Не использовать" на этом методе нету, можно ли его использовать, если да, то в каких случаях?
Также видел в видео, как человек его использовал:) В документации по array такого нету(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), а метод для строк в главе производительность говорится об этом(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

Comment: Вы бы не могли дать точную цитату с MDN, где говорится, что этот метод плох по производительности? Или объяснить, почему вы так решили.

Comment: Извините, забыл - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Comment: Что за значок «не использовать»? Палец вниз?

Comment: Да, этот знак палец вниз

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865710/spread-operator-vs-array-concat здесь интересно описано. Есть еще какой то бенчмарк https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/579/1/arrayprototypeconcat-vs-spread-operator

Comment: Для массивов - используйте :)

Comment: В MDN палец вниз ставят на устаревшие возможности — те которые уже удалены или в будущем будут удалены из стандартов. Т.е. теоретически есть вероятность, что новая версия браузера не будет поддерживать устаревшую возможность. То что у метода проблемы с производительностью, не означает, что он будет удалён, следовательно нет значка. Когда использовать? Когда вас не волнуют проблемы с производительностью.

Comment: @BearVorkuta Чтобы уточнить, когда массивов несколько штук, то нужно использовать конкат. А когда столько, когда уже лень переписывать все массивы спреад?